# How to save state ? AmbilWarnaDialog

Tags: android

How to save the selected color from AmbilWarnaDialog?
For now I only have this:

```
package com.test.testColorPicter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.test.testColorPicter.AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener;

//http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/
public class ColorPicter extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY = "color";
    OnAmbilWarnaListener Listener;

    public TextView tv;
    Button back;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        final int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                ColorPicter.this).getInt(COLOR_PREFERENCE_KEY, Color.WHITE);
        tv.setTextColor(color);
        findViewById(R.id.bu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(
                        ColorPicter.this, 222, new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.i("", "");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                tv.setTextColor(color);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                dialog.show();

                            }

                        });
                dialog.show();

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent start = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(start);
    }

}
```

How do I make when you press OK to save the text in it? Now i see change color but i can't save it.
Please help!. Thanks

How do I make when you press OK to save the text in it?

Please help!. Thanks

Comment: What else should I add to the save color?